# JavaScript - unexpected/strange constructor

Tags: javascript

```
var ninja = {
    name: 'Ninja',
    say: function () {
        return 'I am a ' + this.name;
    }
};

function F(){
}

F.prototype = ninja;

var ninja2 = new F();

ninja2.name;

Output >>> "Ninja"

ninja2.constructor === F

Output >>> false

ninja2.constructor

Output >>> function Object()

ninja2.__proto__ === ninja

Output >>> true
```

In this example, why is not `F` the constructor of `ninja2`
(as one would expect)?!

And I expect that because... the next example prints `Hero`.

```
function Hero(){ } 

var h1 = new Hero();

h1.constructor

Output >>> function Hero()
```

What is the conceptual difference?

I think it's related somehow to the fact that I set explicitly `F.prototype = ninja;` in the first example. But how is it related to that? I am confused about this. Isn't `F` the constructor of `ninja2`? After all `new F()` was used to create `ninja2`?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you made the prototype of `F` an object by stating that `F.prototype = ninja`. `ninja` is of the `Object()` "type". Remember that everything in JavaScript is a function, even objects. Therefore, `F` is an `Object()` now and not a first-class function `F()` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The `constructor` property has no magic, it's just a property that is automatically added when you create a function object:

> [**13.2 Creating Function Objects**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)
>
> - Create a new native ECMAScript object and let *F* be that object.
> - ...
> - Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> - Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments "`constructor`", [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *F*, {
>     [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]:
>     **true**}, and **false**.
> - Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *F* with arguments "`prototype`", [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *proto*,
>     { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]:
>     **false**}, and **false**.
> - ...

Example:

```js
function F(){}
F.prototype.constructor; // F
```

Therefore, when you overwrite `F.prototype` with another object, you lose the `constructor` property.

Then, when you use `ninja2.constructor`, you get `Object` because:

1. `ninja2` has no own `constructor` property.
2. `ninja2` inherits from `ninja`, which has no own `constructor` property.
3. `ninja` inherits from `Object.prototype`, which has an own `constructor` property set to `Object`.

To fix this problem, you can

- Restore `constructor` in `F.prototype`:

  ```js
  function F(){}
  F.prototype = ninja;
  F.prototype.constructor = F;
  ```
- Include `constructor` in `ninja`:

  ```js
  var ninja = {
      constructor: F, /* ... */
  };
  ```
- Add the desired properties to `F.prototype` instead of replacing it with another object:

  ```js
  Object.assign(F.prototype, ninja); /* Requires ECMAScript 6 */
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a lot. "when you override F.prototype, you remove the constructor property." I think you meant "overwrite" here, not "override". Not sure though.

Comment: So when I do `new F()` the JavaScript engine actually looks for (and calls) the `F.prototype`'s constructor, it does not just look for `F` directly. And that `F.prototype`'s constructor is already the Object function because `F.prototype` itself is ninja already (after that set operation `F.prototype = ninja` which I did)? Is that right?

Comment: @peter.petrov `new F` creates an object that inherits from the current `F.prototype`, and calls `F` (see the full process [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2)). In general, `F.prototype` will be an object which inherits from `Object.prototype`, even if you don't overwrite it. The difference is that, before you overwrite it, it has an own `constructor` property. When you overwrite `F.prototype`, you obtain the `constructor` inherited from `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare "F" as follows:

```
function F(){}
```

This will create a function object "F" with a prototype like this:

```
F.prototype = { constructor: F };
```

The "ninja" object you create has the Object() constructor by default. When you replace F.prototype with the "ninja" object, the following line of code now uses the Object() constructor from "ninja" because you overwrote F's prototype:

```
var ninja2 = new F();
```

Comment: This somewhat makes sense to me. I will re-read it a few more times tomorrow and will think about it.

Comment: So when I do `new F()` the JavaScript engine actually looks for (and calls) the F.prototype's constructor, it does not just look for F directly.  And that F.prototype's constructor is already the Object function because F.prototype itself is ninja already (after that set operation `F.prototype = ninja` which I did)? Is that right?

Comment: That is correct. The interpreter will look for the constructor within F's prototype and, not finding one, will eventually fall back to the native Object constructor. This is explained in better detail in the answer provided by Oriol.

Comment: Hm, nice, thank you. I will try to remember that `new F()` is not really `new F()` but it's actually `new F.prototype.constructor()` :) Simply put, that's the whole thing here that caused my confusion.

Comment: Of course, this is probably an oversimplification but ... for now, that's for me a good way to think about it. Thanks again.